# Restrict New Deployments to Kubernetes namespace

Tags: kubernetes, controller, amazon-eks

I need to be able to restrict users from creating new Deployments/ReplicaSets into existing namespace spaces if they don't match a list of approved apps, I assume a custom admission controller would be the best way but I'm unsure how to go about this.

Any solution to do so?

Comment: You don't need an admission controller. You can use RBAC and assign roles to users.

Comment: You can do but will get messy if you want the user to still be able to deploy just not new services to an existing namespace. A policy seems like the use case they where made for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right - if you need to use data like the list of approved apps in an admission control decision you need more than RBAC. You could write a custom admission controller, but a more recommended approach would be to use [Open Policy Agent (OPA)](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/) for this as it gives you the flexibility you need without having to deal with low-level API server integration concerns.

Check out [OPA Gatekeeper](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper) for an open source integration of OPA with Kubernetes, or [Styra](https://www.styra.com/) for a commercial solution.

Finally, [Kyverno](https://kyverno.io/) is an alternative to OPA for policy-based admission control on Kubernetes.